# Many tasks but cores not fully used

Tags: c#, task

I am creating a program which creates alot of tasks. Usually the number of tasks is 10,000 to 50,000. The program use a very minimal amount of locks, about one in 800,000, so the threads are most likely not blocking eachother. However, my cpu use is still only 70%. I have two questions about this.

- Is 50k an excessive amount of tasks?
- Should my CPU use be at 100%, or is 70% normal in this scenario? If it is not, I will have to look into my locking again.

I am creating a program which creates alot of tasks. Usually the number of tasks is 10,000 to 50,000. The program use a very minimal amount of locks, about one in 800,000, so the threads are most likely not blocking eachother. However, my cpu use is still only 70%. I have two questions about this.

- Is 50k an excessive amount of tasks?
- Should my CPU use be at 100%, or is 70% normal in this scenario? If it is not, I will have to look into my locking again.

**Task information**

The tasks are used for a breath-first search algorithm.
One task computes the hash of a node which is specific for this task. It then looks the node up in a hash table using this hash. The hash is very fast. The lookup is usually pretty fast too.

Comment: 50k is a lot for anything!

Comment: "or is 70% normal in this scenario" Which scenario? What are your tasks doing?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained what the task does. Give me a sec

Comment: Well, *something* is blocking a lot. Otherwise the threads would be on the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reaching a higher percentage of CPU usage precisely because you have *too many* active threads.
Whenever a thread exhausts its CPU time slice and gives way for another thread to execute something on the CPU, something called "context switching" happens.
This basically saves the current state of the yielding thread (e.g., its stack), and restores the state of the second thread.
This is a fairly expensive operation, and it's time spent doing nothing useful. This *might* be the reason.

Comment: Okay. It is possible for me to combine alot of tasks into one here. What do you recommend is a good amount of tasks? twice the amount of cores?

Comment: This does not apply, unless the tasks are long-running or blocking.

Comment: @AartStuurman make an experiment and see for yourself. Start with 1x number of cores, measure the time, and increment. Optimal number of tasks depends on the code, and is very difficult to determine without actually running the code.

Comment: Try determining how many actual threads are being spawned. Then try limiting the number of threads spawned by TPL. Using a custom task scheduler is one of the options (there might be more): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351

Comment: 50k tasks do not mean 50k threads *in any way*. Not even approximately. Tasks are meant to be spawned in much bigger numbers than there are cores. Also, context switching does not lead to an underutilized CPU. It means wasted cycles, but the machine is not idle. Given the problem description in the question, this answer does not apply.